# How to config hdfs in hadoop

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, hadoop

```
namita@ubuntu:~/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1$ jps
5201 DataNode
5429 Jps
4199 SecondaryNameNode
4299 JobTracker
4972 NameNode
4527 TaskTracker
namita@ubuntu:~/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls
ls: Cannot access .: No such file or directory.
```

How hdfs file configure in hadoop .. .. please send the code to fix it..

Comment: Unclear what you're asking?

Comment: He's asking why the result is "cannot access .: no such file or directory". I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running hadoop in pseudo distributed mode or in stand alone mode.
And you have start all the daemons. try running .start_all.sh file which will start all the daemons in your hadoop. Basically it will start all your master node and slaves node in your cluster.

Comment: Is obvious he has already started all daemons. in fact he listed "jps" result

Answer (score 0):

do this command:

```
Usage: hdfs dfs -ls <args>
```

Example:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hadoop/file1
```

Exit Code:

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html

Answer (score -1):

The solution is quite simple...but I cannot understand why. 
Try this:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir foo
```

And then you shouldn't have "no such file"